# The "add music" button seems to randomly appear on the videos I upload to YouTube

Tags: youtube

The "add music" button seems to randomly appear on the videos I upload to YouTube. For example, I uploaded 2 videos without music track, yet only one has the "add music" button:

[image]

Any idea why?

- Video 1 (without "add music"): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWbGbflkwvE
- Video 2 (with "add music"): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbzEtwoBi3Q

Answer (score 1):

The first video is private. Not being published, and having non-standard licensing settings will prevent you adding music.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because one of the videos has a lot of noise and the other one doesn't, so Youtube decides that you wouldn't want music on the one with a lot of noise but you would like some on the one with little noise.

Just a guess, but I hope that it helps!

Comment: Thanks but both videos has no sound track at all, i.e. neither music nor noise. I added links to the two videos in the question.

Comment: Ok. sorry that doesn't work. Again, it was just a guess. After watching the videos, I am still stumped.